# Sagepay magento extension. Test mode

Tags: magento, opayo

How do I make a test account to test the plugin in magento? I put the extension in test mode. And when I press "PLACE Order" writes "Your card has not been charged!"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a support forum for the free plugin here http://ebizmarts.com/forums and if you are using the PRO module, you can just use the contact form here http://ebizmarts.com/contact-us

Also, the problem you mention is described on the Wiki here http://wiki.ebizmarts.com/sage-pay-common-problems

Especially you can check this link. **http://ebizmarts.com/forums/topics/view/7503**

Hope this helps you !!